# Jetpack compose LauncherForActivityResult executes onResult directly without showing permission request dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

in my code i'm trying to check for external storage write permission and for that i'm using LauncherForActivityResult. i've seen some examples of it and in all examples launching the launcher would show the request permission dialog. but in my code what happens is that the launcher's onResult function is executed without showing any request dialog. why is that happening?

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    activity: ComponentActivity,
    mainScreenViewModel: MainScreenViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    val storagePerm=Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
    MVBroadcastBridge.mainScreenViewModel = mainScreenViewModel;
    val context = LocalContext.current;
    val requestPermissionLauncher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
            contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
            onResult = { isGranted: Boolean ->
                if (isGranted) {
                    //onPermissionGranted()
                    mainScreenViewModel.writeExternalPermission = true;
                } else {
                    //onPermissionDenied()
                    mainScreenViewModel.writeExternalPermission = false;
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "App can't work correctly without permission",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        )

    var isPermissionGranted = mainScreenViewModel.writeExternalPermission;

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        mainScreenViewModel.initializeProcess();
        mainScreenViewModel.retrievePowerLevel();

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, storagePerm) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            mainScreenViewModel.writeExternalPermission = true;
            println("I have permission")
        } else {
            println("I Don't have permission")
        }
    }

    if(!mainScreenViewModel.writeExternalPermission){
        SideEffect {
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(storagePerm)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What Android version are you testing this on? That permission can never be granted on [Android 13 and higher](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions). You shouldn't be requesting this permission at all, so it would be helpful if you could explain what you are trying to to do with that permission so we can point you to what you should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can request permission using the google accompanist library.

Firstly, Add Dependency in `build.gradle(app-level)`

```
 implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:0.31.0-alpha")
```

Then add you permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
```

Define a state variable. we are using `rememberPermissionState` because we require only one permission at a time.

```
val writePermission = rememberPermissionState(
    permission = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
)
```

Request Permission

```
if (!writePermission.status.isGranted) {
    writePermission.launchPermissionRequest()
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Given Already", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

And It's Done !!